# Fourier series problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the function $f\left(x\right)$ defined for $0<x<1$ by
$$f\left(x\right)=x-x^2$$

I want to determine the fourier sine series and fourier cosine series of f.

my attempt

Recall that $$a_0=\frac{2}{L}∫_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx$$
ie $a_0=\frac{1}{3}$

and $$a_n=\frac{2}{L}∫_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)\cos \left(\frac{nπ x}{L}\right)dx$$ where $L=1$ in this case

ie $$a_n=2\left[∫_{0}^{1}x\cos \left(nπ x\right)dx-∫_{0}^{1}x^2\cos \left(nπ x\right)dx\right]$$

i assume i then use intergration by parts twice to solve for $a_n$

Now calculating $b_n$

$$b_n=\frac{2}{L} ∫_0^{1} f\left(x\right)\sin \left(\frac{nπ x}{L}\right)dx$$

$$b_n=2\left[∫_0^{1}x\sin \left(nπ x\right)dx-∫_0^{1}x^2\sin \left(nπ x\right)dx\right]$$

and again i assume we can use integration by parts twice here?

can anyone tell me if i'm going wrong anywhere here

Comment: You are right. Take care that the first coefficient of the cosine series is $\frac{a_0}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Technically **correct**, but:

For the fourier cosine series, it extends $f(x)$ over a period of $2l$ i.e. $-1 < x < 1$. This makes $f(x)$ into a even function, therefore the FCS of $f(x)$ is also an even function and therefore can only contain even terms.
therefore only need to calculate an.

When calculating an's:

perform integration by parts on $2( x - x^2)\cos(n\pi x)$ between limits 0 and 1
please dont make the mistake of just integrating between -1 and 1

$f(x) = x-x^2$ is not even, the extension is odd. i.e. $f(x)$ does not equal the FCS of $f(x)$ in the way the maths interprets it anyway. believe me!

Also for the FCS, the graph on maple won't look like it is right, it just hasn't converged yet.

Tremendous!

Comment: i dont need to plot it on maple, this is from  a textbook

Comment: Must be a hell of a coincidence then.

Comment: The book is called Elementary differential equations and boundary value problems by william e. boyce and richard c.diprima page 621 question 26

Answer (score 1):

In order to make clear of what Fourier series it is about :

[image]

[A typo corrected in last equation.]

Comment: $f(x) =  \{x\}-\{x\}^2$ where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ (otherwise it suggests not looking for the convergence at the boundary of $(0,1)$).  Since $f(x)$ is continuous and $C^1$ on $(0,1)$ its Fourier series converges uniformly

Comment: I think that there is a small ambiguity in the wording of the question. it should be more precise about the definitions of function and kind of Fourier Series concerned, in order to avoid some discussion.

Comment: brilliant, may i ask what program you used to plot them graphs?

Comment: I this case, I used Mathcad.